# Scala Cats: Iterate over a result from a free monad and execute a free monad operation for each of those results

Tags: scala, free-monad, scala-cats

Lets say I have the following free monad definition:

```
sealed trait SetOpsA[A]
case class AllSetNames() extends SetOpsA[Set[String]]
case class IdsFromSet(setName: String) extends SetOpsA[Set[String]]

object SetOps {
  type SetOps[A] = Free[SetOpsA, A]

  def allSetNames(): SetOps[Set[String]] =
    liftF[SetOpsA, Set[String]](AllSetNames())

  def idsFromSet(setName: String): SetOps[Set[String]] =
    liftF[SetOpsA, Set[String]](IdsFromSet(setName))
}
```

Now I would like to retrieve all set names and then for each of these set names execute the idsFromSet action.

I would describe it like this:

```
val prog = for {
  allSetNames <- allSetNames()
  setName <- allSetNames
  ids <- idsFromSet(setName)
} yield ids
```

But this is not possible since monads can't be mixed in for comprehensions. So on the line 'setName <- allSetNames' the compiler complains that it is given a Set and it wants a Free.

By looking around it seems that a monad transformer would be the way to go. But with this information I am really lost since the examples with monad transformers I can find seem to be too far away from my example or the explanations too abstract for me to implment it in this example. So some help with this would be appreciated.

Edit: I am a step further and can sort of achieve my result by doing this (I also realized I want the flattened ids, and not a collection of collection of ids):

```
val prog = for {
  allSetNames <- allSetNames()
  ids <-  allSetNames.toList.traverseU(idsFromSet)
} yield ids.flatten
```